# Finding mean of dataframe values based on values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

So I'm trying to find the mean of values in dataframe 1 where the values of dataframe 2 are equal to 1. Is there an easy way to do this?

Example:

```
    Dataframe 1:
           product1 product2 product3
    user1   2         4          5
    user2   1         3          4
    user3   3         2          1
    
    Dataframe 2: 
            product1 product2 product3
    user1   0        1        0
    user2   1        0        1
    user3   0        0        1
```

So, I'd end up with taking a mean of these values:

```
    Mean Dataframe:
         product1  product2 product3
    user1          4
    user2 1                 4
    user3                   1
```

So the mean, naturally, would be 2.5
However, in my example, I have approx 3000 rows and 300 columns, so cannot just use .loc[column == x] as there are too many columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is same index and same columns values use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df3 = df1.where(df2.eq(1))
```